# Define an Identity increment on a Bigint field will create many gaps

Tags: sql-server, biginteger

I have a Bigint column which is set as the primary key + Identity increment by 1 as follow inside SQL server 2016,:-

[image]

but when i checked the records that are been added, i found many gaps inside the bigint, as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice what is going on? now if i add successive records the increment will be by 1, but when time passes there will be gaps..

Comment: Gaps are expected in a `IDENTITY`. It is by design.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected gaps in IDENTITY column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column)

Comment: @Larnu very strange and is there a way to fix this? i did not face these issues on sql server 2008

Comment: SQL Server 2008 had the same feature. It's not strange, as it's by design. An `IDENTITY` is to ensure that the value is always increasing, based on the seed, that's it. It is not expected to fill gaps, nor is it expected for every value to be sequential. `IDENTITY`, on it's own, doesn't even guarantee uniqueness; that's what a PK or Unique Constraint/Index is for.

Comment: @testtest it's not strange nor is there anything to fix. All an IDENTITY column needs to do is generate incrementing numbers. They don't have to be contiguous. Besides, if you delete a record, you'll have gaps anyway

Comment: A better question is, why do you want to avoid gaps? Is there an actual business reason, eg generating invoice numbers that *can't* have gaps? You may be able to solve this with a SEQUENCE, or require a more complex solution in code.

Comment: In your reporting, if you need sequential numbers just use Seq = row_number() over (order by id)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but if we have an int or bigint and they keep creating gaps we will reach the column max number for int(max) or bigint(max).. is this correct? or i am overthinking...

Comment: @JohnCappelletti i am just afraid that i might reach the int or bigint max values very quickly...

Comment: `bigint` has a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, you've got a long way before you reach it's maximum value. Considering, however, how often you're skipping numbers, it sounds like you're having a lot of (unexpected) restarts of your instance; as you shouldn't get those skips if you stop the instance/server safely and properly. That could be a problem you should be looking at.

Comment: If Larnu's bigint number is not cause for pause, try this :  nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred seven

Comment: Or, to put it in another perspective, you've used 0.000000000001681%~ of the numbers you can fit in a `bigint`, and that *assumes* you started at 1 and will never use 0 to -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.